# Erro: unknown type name

Tags: c

Estou tendo problemas com a chamada de um struct, no arquivo c ela está assim

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "AVL.h"

typedef struct no NO;
struct no {
    int chave;
    struct NO *fesq;
    struct NO *fdir;
    int altura;
};
```

quando chamo alguma função do tipo

```
NO *avl_cria_no(int ch) {
    NO *no = (NO *) malloc(sizeof (NO));
    if (no != NULL)
    {
        no->altura = 0;
        no->fdir = NULL;
        no->fesq = NULL;
        no->chave = ch;
    }
    return no;
}
```

o único erro que recebo é **error: unknown type name ‘NO’**. O que eu preciso fazer?

Answer (score 2):

O problema está na ordem de como o código é interpretado.

Primeiro está a incluir e interpretar o arquivo "AVL.h" que usa a estrutura NO e só depois ela é escrita no código no main por isso ele diz que não existe:

> unknown type name ‘NO’

Só trocando a ordem dos dois já resolve o erro de compilação:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


typedef struct no NO; //antes do include AVL.h
struct no {
    int chave;
    struct NO *fesq;
    struct NO *fdir;
    int altura;
};

#include "AVL.h" //a seguir ao struct
```

Agora tenha em mente que esta não é particularmente a melhor solução, pois é mais comum ter os includes no topo. Então uma alternativa que tem para organizar tudo é criar um arquivo que apenas define a estrutura NO e incluir esse antes:

NO.h:

```
typedef struct no NO;
struct no {
    int chave;
    struct NO *fesq;
    struct NO *fdir;
    int altura;
};
```

main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "NO.h"
#include "AVL.h"
```

Se por ventura houver algum arquivo que também precise da definição desta estrutura basta incluir diretamente o novo .h

Nota: Recomendo que use os famosos *header guards* para prevenir que inclusão repetida de um arquivo se transforme num erro. O NO.h com um *header guard* ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
#ifndef NO_H_INCLUDED
#define NO_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct no NO; 
struct no {
    int chave;
    struct NO *fesq;
    struct NO *fdir;
    int altura;
};


#endif // NO_H_INCLUDED
```